# React native multiple ref to global component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create multiple ref's to the same global component. Like for example TextInput , if i want to add ref to it i use. this in my class based component :

```
 <TextInput
               
                  ref={input => {
                    this.secondTextInput = input;
                  }}
                
                />
```

and then call via `this.secondTextInput.focus();` to focus the textinput.  It works as long im importing the whole textInput directly in my class.

Similiarly if ive created a global component for TextInput in another file  like :

```
export const OTPInput = props => {
  return (
    
      <TextInput
        placeholder={props.title}
        onChangeText={props.onTextEnter}
        value={props.value}
      
      />
   
  );
};
```

and using this in my classes by importing  like :

```
Class ABC extends Component{


render(){
return(
<>
<OTPInput title ="first otp" />
<OTPInput title ="another otp" />
</>
)

}

}
```

How can i create ref and pass it , so that i can focus the text input by clicking some button in my class func .

Any help would be greatful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

```
export const OTPInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <TextInput
    ref={ref}
    placeholder={props.title}
    onChangeText={props.onTextEnter}
    value={props.value}  
  />
));
```

Then as per your example usage, just create a ref and attach

```
const OTPInputRef1 = React.createRef();

...

<OTPInput ref={OTPInputRef1} title ="first otp" />
```

Comment: oh okay,  and how to focus the textfield? OTPInputRef1.focus() will do?

Comment: @GauravRoy Ah, yes, if you are using the older style [Callback Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs), but if using the current method of [accessing react refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs) then more likely `OTPInputRef1.current.focus()`.

Comment: thanks a ton,it surely does focus now. Brilliant :D ,  just one doubt, i have my text inputalready populated with redux value, but when it focuses it loses the value assigned to it. bit curios

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Forwarding refs described here in the react documents
https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html